# Show that any four polynomials in $P_2$ are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

[[image: Attempted solution[1]]I attempted this question but just wanted to check if I'm on the right track.

I started the question by :

Let { ($a_o$+$a_1$$x^2$), ($a_o$-$a_1$$x^2$), ($a_1$$x^2$-$a_0$), ($a_1$$x^2$-$a_2$x) ∈ $P_2$

Followed by putting in vector form and into a matrix, reducing it to row echelon form and comparing the rank to the number of columns to determine it is lenearly dependent. Am I right to do it this way?

Comment: What dimension is $P_2$? How many linearly independent vectors can be in an $n$ dimensional space?

Comment: would the dimension be 4?

Comment: To begin with, $P_2$ is the set of all polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most $2$, i.e. $P_2=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2~:~a_1,a_2,a_3\in\Bbb R\}$.  It looks like you are maybe looking at a very specific set of four polynomials, or maybe you are intending to take four arbitrary polynomials but you are missing a term from each... in either event this would be incorrect.  Note that $P_2$ is of dimension ___ because of _____  and so if you have four polynomials since four is greater than _____ this implies that ______ because of ______.

Comment: @Jenny not quite. How did you arrive at that number?

Comment: I got the number from the question, since it said any four polynomials so i thought it would be 4 sets and thus the dimension would be 4

Comment: @Jenny In a space of dimension 4, you could have 4 linearly independent vectors, but not 5.  That's what the dimension means, essentially.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis for the space.  The vectors in a basis for a space $V$ must be linearly independent and must span the entirety of $V$.  For example, the basis $\{[1,0],[0,1]\}$ acts as a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ so $\Bbb R^2$ is of dimension $2$.  A common beginner exercise is to prove that any two bases for the same space must have the same number of vectors, so defining dimension in this way is unambiguous.  Another common exercise is to show that any set of $n$ vectors in an $m$-dimensional space where $n>m$ must be linearly dependent.

Comment: I attached an image of my attempted solution. Would this be the right way to address the question?

Comment: No.  I will reiterate and reemphasize my earlier point.  You have shown that a *particular* and *very specific* collection of four vectors in $P_2$ happen to be linearly dependent.  This is not sufficient proof to show that **all** collections of four vectors in $P_2$ are linearly dependent.  Proof by example works only to show that there exists *at least one* situation where the claim is true, but it does not work for addressing the claim that it is *true always* for *all* situations.

Comment: Something else weird and awkward about your attempt is that you end with the line "$rank(A)=3\neq \text{# of columns}\implies\text{linearly dependent}$... but $3$ *is* the number of columns... with the way you set it up you mean to say that it is not the number of *rows*.  Keep track of the difference between setting your vectors to test independence as the rows versus as the columns and what the result of the row reduction will give you.  If you have trouble remembering, think of one of the easier examples of using the vector $[1,1,1,1]$.